# I would like to set up a backtest strategy on Tradingview using Pinescript. I would like to use SMA and RSI as indicators. How to write the script?

Tags: pine-script, trading, crossover

I would like to set up a backtest strategy on Tradingview using Pinescript. I would like to use SMA and RSI as indicators. I want the start date to be January 1, 2007 and the end date to be March 31, 2009 of the testing period. Can someone write up a script? This is what I currently have but it doesn't seem to be filtering out the start and end dates to the testing period.

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

// Indicators
SMA50 = sma(close, 50)
SMA100 = sma(close, 100)
rsi = rsi(close, 14)
atr = atr(14)

// Crossover conditions 
longCondition = crossover(SMA50, SMA100)

if (longCondition)
    stopLoss = low - atr * 2
    takeProfit = high + atr * 6
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, 100, when = rsi > 30)
    strategy.exit ("exit", "long", stop=stopLoss, limit=takeProfit)
    
    
// Plotting SMAs in the chart.
plot(SMA50)
plot(SMA100,color=color.black)
```

Comment: Use this example

https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-do-i-implement-date-range-filtering-in-strategies

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=4
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)

// Indicators
SMA50 = sma(close, 50)
SMA100 = sma(close, 100)
rsi = rsi(close, 14)
atr = atr(14)


// === BACKTEST RANGE ===
fromMonth = input(defval = 1,    title = "From Month",      type = input.integer, minval = 1, maxval = 12)
fromDay   = input(defval = 1,    title = "From Day",        type = input.integer, minval = 1, maxval = 31)
fromYear  = input(defval = 2007, title = "From Year",       type = input.integer, minval = 1970)
thruMonth = input(defval = 3,    title = "Thru Month",      type = input.integer, minval = 1, maxval = 12)
thruDay   = input(defval = 31,    title = "Thru Day",        type = input.integer, minval = 1, maxval = 31)
thruYear  = input(defval = 2009, title = "Thru Year",       type = input.integer, minval = 1970)


// === FUNCTION ===
start     = timestamp(fromYear, fromMonth, fromDay, 00, 00)        // backtest start window
finish    = timestamp(thruYear, thruMonth, thruDay, 23, 59)        // backtest finish window
window()  => time >= start and time <= finish ? true : false  

// Crossover conditions 
longCondition = crossover(SMA50, SMA100)

if (longCondition)
    stopLoss = low - atr * 2
    takeProfit = high + atr * 6
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, 100, when = rsi > 30 and window())
    strategy.exit ("exit", "long", stop=stopLoss, limit=takeProfit)
    
if not window ()
    strategy.close ("long")
    
// Plotting SMAs in the chart.
plot(SMA50)
plot(SMA100,color=color.black)
```

**I hope it helps you, in this link you have more information:**

https://www.tradingview.com/script/62hUcP6O-How-To-Set-Backtest-Date-Range/

Comment: Kindly describe where you are facing the error!